# admin theme changes to default at editing page, Themekey module

Tags: theme-negotiation

Using the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module, I have changed the theme of user role (EDITOR) to Administration theme. So, when the user of this role logs in, he gets admin theme.

It works find but when he edit something the theme changes back to default. I want to have admin theme, even at editing pages for this user role. Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. I had to deselect the administration theme when editing or creating content, in admin/appearance.